# Disable IntelliJ Method Path Toolbar

Tags: intellij-idea

I am not sure which tool bar this is:

[image]

The "SymanJunitXo | RECOMMENDED_CANDIDATES_ITEMS" tells me what path my cursor is currently on. I want to disable it and can't figure out which it this is.